# Why does django stops loading a page after opening several pages?

Tags: python, django, windows

I have several django projects and they work well on my desktop. But when I run them on my laptop, they run ok for sometime. Then on a random occasion, opening a page won't work. The browser keeps trying to load the page (title tab keeps spinning, URL changes to the page its trying to open, and the page turns blank), while the development server (django on windows shell) says it has successfully served the page (200 status).

This behavior is consistent among Firefox, IE and Chrome. I tried changing ports, using machine IP instead of localhost, loading static files on external server, but nothing works. I tried opening the site (using laptop computer name) from desktop browsers and behaves the same. Another interesting thing is, even if I shutdown and restart the django server, I wont be able to open the page that have failed previously unless I close the loading page.

My laptop is running a basic Windows 8, while desktop is Windows 8 Pro. I think the windows version has something to do with it.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I hope I made myself clear. Thanks.

Comment: django's built-in `runserver` has a connection limit (among other limits, such has having a limited queue size); if you hit this limit, it will stop serving new pages. This might be what you are facing.

Comment: Could be, because it seems like the problem is triggered when I click on a link even before the current page has finished loading. But I don't understand why those unloaded elements would not be aborted to free up resources.

Comment: Btw, just to clarify, I'm opening those pages on a single window/tab.

Comment: Well your browser could still be sending requests for resources for the previous request; while you click on something to be loaded for a new request. These multiple requests could be overwhelming `runserver`. If you run it with a (proper) wsgi container, I am sure these issues will dissipate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks people for your comments and answer. I uninstalled from the laptop each application that is not present in the desktop and found which one is causing the problem. [This app called NetWorx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) has a network filtering that I enabled and for some reason its blocking the django response. I disabled network filtering which is good enough for my need.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell whether the issue is related to Windows specifically, rather than compatibility issues with images/CSS/Javascript/plugins such as Flash. Are you running the latest versions of those browsers (or at least the same versions as on your desktop)? Do you have different security software/firewalls? Do other sites load inconsistently? Seems unlikely to be a Django issue (although you can try loading sites like djangoproject.com).

Comment: Firewall is the same. djangoproject.com should not be a problem because the server is not running on the laptop. Browser version should not be an issue because the problem happens also in desktop browsers if the server is running on the laptop. Likewise, laptop browsers are ok when server is running on the desktop.

Comment: Other sites behaves the same when run on django local server. Thanks for asking clarifications. This laptop is using AMD processor, might be unreasonable but I have a feeling that it has something to do with it. Or maybe it has something to do with Windows version. I just cant figure out how to fix it :(